# how patch training for xor in neural network works?

Tags: neural-network, patch

how to calculate the error for xor patch training in neural network before updating the weights? for example if i got the following feed forward result :

```
x|y| output
1|1|0.9
1|0|0.65
0|1|0.08
0|0|0.14
```

should i calculate the RSE(or MSE doesn't matter) to get the value that will be used in calculating the delta for weights update?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to get the gradient from the error metric?

Comment: sorry if the question wasn't clear, I understand now that to update weights in patch training we have to sum the delta weights for the elements  and then update the weight after training the whole data set, my question is after I update the weights how I evaluate the error ? depending on which element error ? as you can see in XOR training i have 4 elements

Comment: It's batch training btw. You don't need the global error, just the error for each example, which can be used to do backpropagation, and calculate the gradient of each weight for that example. Add that to the each weight's total gradient, and when you are done with every example, then update the weights.